# Unknow URL Scheme from webView "tel:"

Tags: android, html, webview, href, action

handsome

I tried to Intent "action_dial" from webview. It doesn't perfectly works.
When I click  "href tag", it open error page then call dial page,too.
error page message is "unknown_url_scheme". please help me

Here is my code

```
<a href= "tel:02-6285-0085"> 02-6285-0085</a>
```

Android

```
    webview.setWebViewClient((WebViewClient) (new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(@NotNull WebView view, @NotNull WebResourceRequest request) {
     Uri uri = request.getUrl();               
     if (uri.getScheme().equals("tel")){
               
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
                    startActivity(intent); //
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once if condition need to change in your current code.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
        try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
                    startActivity(intent); //
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }
    return false;
}
```